# Nested loop based on json response in Terraform for multiple resource target

Tags: terraform, resources

Array:

```
regions = [
        {name: "region1"}, 
        {name: "region2"}, 
        {name: "region3"}, 
        {name: "region4"}, 
        {name: "region5"}, 
        {name: "region6"}]
```

Json:

```
{
    "region1" : ["cluster1"],
    "region2" : [],
    "region3" : ["cluster1"],
    "region4" : ["cluster1","cluster2"]
}


resource "type" "name" {
     count = length(regionLength)
     name = "region-name/cluster-name"
}
```

I need resource created with such name output like this

- region1/cluster1
- region2
- region3/cluster1
- region4/cluster1
- region4/cluster2

Can we achieve this too:
Final = []

```
For r , cs in arr: 
    for oc in regions:
        if r == oc.name:
            for c in cs:    
                oc[‘cluster’] = r-c
                Final.push(oc)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: Every question is unique. It is just a perspective. I followed the rest of the answer solution and though I dont know how to accept it. However Few answers were really great and they worked for me.

Comment: I would suggest revising those answers and accept them. To do it you click a 'tick' button under up/down vote buttons. Also your current question is not clear.

Comment: okay. Understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that as folllows:

```
variable "regions" {
    default = {
    "region1" : ["cluster1"],
    "region2" : [],
    "region3" : ["cluster1"],
    "region4" : ["cluster1","cluster2"]
    }
}


locals {
    region_list = flatten([for region, clusters in var.regions:
                      [  for cluster in coalescelist(clusters, [""]):
                         "${region}/${cluster}" 
                      ]
                   ])
}
```

which gives:

```
region_list = [
  "region1/cluster1",
  "region2/",
  "region3/cluster1",
  "region4/cluster1",
  "region4/cluster2",
]
```

Comment: One more addition to the above question @Marcin: I am adding question. let me know your idea